# Is there a way I could optimize multiple python for loops?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am trying to make a multiplayer web game, I have a server done in python. Since the game is multiplayer, I need to update each player individually; This requires `for` loops, at the moment my code uses a lot of for loops, which is causing me some unwanted side affects. The side affects includes slowed speeds. Another issue i have with for loops is they change speeds depending on how many things they are looping through; This is causing problems with the fact that the number of items that the loop needs to loop through changes depending on how many players are connected, thus messing up the client side prediction function I made to mask lag.

This is my main code:

```
      PlayerData = {} 

    for Player in Players:
        if(Player.id > 50):
            PlayerData['playerx' + str(Player.id)] = Player.x
            PlayerData['playery' + str(Player.id)] = Player.y


            PlayerData['playera' + str(Player.id)] = int(Player.angle)

            PlayerData['playerstat' + str(Player.id)] = Player.alive

            if(Player.id > 50):
                if(Player.alive == 0):
                    Players.remove(Player) 

        for ID in clientIds:
            PlayerData['id'] = str(clientIds[len(clientIds) - 1].id)

        PlayerData['players'] = ids




        if(Player.id <= 50):
            hrIds.append(Player.id)
            PlayerData['hx' + str(Player.id)] = Player.x
            PlayerData['hy' + str(Player.id)] = Player.y
            #PlayerData['ha' + str(Player.id)] = int(Player.angle)


    PlayerData['hr'] = hrIds
    PlayerJsonData = json.dumps(PlayerData)
    await websocket.send(PlayerJsonData)
    recivedData = await websocket.receive()
    rData = json.loads(recivedData)

    for ID in clientIds:
        if(rData['id'] == str(ID.id)):
            if(ID.IG == 0):
                 if(rData['playerstat'] == 1):
                    Players.append(player_classes.Basic(-1300, -1300, ID.ws, ID.id, 1)) 
                    ID.IG = 1




    for Player in Players:

        for Player2 in Players:
             if(Player.id > 50):
                Player.detect_collide(Player2)


                if(rData['id'] == str(Player.id)):
                    if(rData['direction'] == "up"):
                            Player.accelerate(rData['direction'])
                            Player.moveUp(Player2)

                    if(rData['direction'] == "left"):
                        Player.accelerate(rData['direction'])
                        Player.moveLeft(Player2)

                    if(rData['direction'] == "down"):
                        Player.accelerate(rData['direction'])
                        Player.moveDown(Player2)

                    if(rData['direction'] == "right"):
                        Player.accelerate(rData['direction'])
                        Player.moveRight(Player2)


                    if(rData['direction'] == "none"):
                        Player.decelerate(rData['direction'])
```

EDIT: My main looping speed issue happens when I add more classes to `Players`

Comment: The second pair of nested for loops looks redundant, unless it's a typo? `for Player in Players` then `for Player2 in Players` iterates through players n^2 times?

Comment: That is not a typo, The purpose of that is `detect_collide` requires two players to be compared for collisions.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid checking the collision of the same pair of players twice.

Let's take a very simple example with `Players` list containing 0, 1, 2, 3.

With your code you get a lot of redundant tests:

- At loop 0 you test 0 against 1, 2 and 3
- At loop 1 you test 1 against 0, 2 and 3 ===> (but 0-1 was already tested)
- At loop 2 you test 2 against 0, 1 and 3 ===> (but 0-2 / 1-2 were already tested)
- At loop 3 you test 3 against 0, 1 and 2 ===> (but 0-3 / 1-3 / 2-3 were already tested)

So instead of:

```
for Player in Players:
    for Player2 in Players:
```

Do:

```
for i, Player in enumerate(Players):
    for Player2 in Players[i + 1:]:
```

If we use the list containing 0, 1, 2, 3 once again, we have the following behavior:

- At loop 0 you test 0 against 1, 2, 3
- At loop 1 you test 1 against 2, 3
- At loop 2 you test 2 against 3

This way, it cuts the number of iterations from N^2 to N(N-1)/2.

Comment: This does not seem to work for me, the detect collide function requires all of the players in game to be compared. A way to think of it is one player is chosen, then that player needs to be compared to all other players.

Comment: No, you're redundantly testing the same pairs of players twice in your code, while my code would test each player pair exactly once. I've updated my answer to give you a better explanation.

Comment: I tried it, but for some reason detect_collide does not get triggered.

Comment: Is `Players` a list? The above code assumes it's a list. If not, you should adapt the code to make it indexable.

Comment: So you mean `detect_collide` doesn't run even once? It must be something else in your code then. Try my loop in isolation in a little test snippet and you'll see how it works.